# ¿Puedo meter una condición if dentro de una ya establecida en JavaScript usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, botón

¡Hola! No sé por qué no me salta la segunda condición dentro de la inicial. Solamente me salta el primer *console.log*. ¿Hay algo que me estaría faltando para que salte?

Ya logré plantear esta propuesta anteriormente, pero mi objetivo principal sería optimizar de la mejor manera posible el código para no tener que repetir o usar tantas lineas innecesarias como planteé anteriormente. Pensé que una de las maneras sería la siguiente:

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarCosto);

let kilometros;
let tipoAuto;

function determinarCosto(){
    kilometros = Number($("#btnKilometros").val());
    tipoAuto = $("#slcTipoAuto").val();

    if(tipoAuto === "A"){
        console.log("Yes");
        if(kilometros <= 300) {
            console.log(`menor o igual a 300`);
        }

    }else{
        console.log("No");
    }
}
```

Les puedo dejar el HTML también de referencia:

```
<body>
    <label for="txtKilometros">Ingresar kilómetros:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtKilometros">
    <label for="slcTipoAuto">Tipo de auto:</label>
    <select id="slcTipoAuto">
        <option value="A">Económico</option>
        <option value="B">Lujo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Y cuando haces pruebas cuánto vale kilómetros?

Comment: Pruebo con 300 o menor a eso y no me salta mensaje en la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve revisando tu código y parece que tienes un error al querer obtener el valor de los kilómetros usando el elemento `btnKilometros` en lugar del `txtKilometros` ya que `txtKilometros` es el que almacena el valor ingresado por el usuario.

Tienes que cambiar la siguiente línea de código:

```
kilometros = Number($("#btnKilometros").val());
```

Por esta:

```
kilometros = Number($("#txtKilometros").val());
```

Ocupar el selector incorrecto te está ocasionando que la condición de que kilómertos sea menor o igual a 300 no se cumpla (este valor lo ejemplificaste en una de tus respuesta en la pregunta).